# toLocaleTimeString doesn't convert time to 12 hour format in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a `Text` tag in `expo/react-native` which i use on a screen to show live time using JavaScript `new Date()` object. Its giving me 24 hour format even when i set `"en-US"` and `hour12: true` i have tried everything but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
const [liveTime, setLiveTime] = useState(new Date())

const refreshLiveTime = () => {
    setLiveTime(new Date())
  }

useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(refreshLiveTime, 1000)
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerId)
    }
}, [])
```

And here is how i render it in `Text`  tag:

```
<Text>{liveTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {hour12: true})}</Text>
```

Sample Expected output:

```
01:12:18
```

Output i am receiving:

```
13:12:18
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the same code in `reactjs` and it works fine there, i think the problem is with `react-native` here, maybe react-native doesn't support `toLocaleTimeString()`

Comment: It seems to be 12 hr format by default for `en-US` from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#using_locales) ...

Comment: yes, at first i just used toLocaleTimeString() but still the same

Comment: can you add a reproducible sample maybe some a sandbox kindof

Comment: i just tried the same code on sandbox but using reactjs and it works fine in reactjs

Comment: sorry I'm not sure if it work differently in RN ...

Answer (score 1):

Format date with locales is not supported by  Expo or React Native by default on Android.

In case you are using bare React Native, you can add JavaScriptCore Flavors to Android to enable Internationalization API.

in `android/app/build.gradle` enable this line

```js
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
```

Note: Enabling internationalization on android will add an extra 2MB to your app APK. Review whether it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), try [my example](https://playcode.io/1010768):

```
import moment from 'moment';

const time = new Date();
console.log(moment(time).format("hh:mm:ss"));
// if you want display by 24h, change hh:mm:ss to HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: tried it but still same problem

Comment: @NasyxNadeem I modified my example.

Comment: trued ut but, nothing, i have also updated the question please check last part

Comment: @NasyxNadeem i'm not using Date of JS and related function, do you want use third party library like `moment`?

Comment: @NasyxNadeem i updated. you need add `moment` package.

Comment: but if i do this, will the seconds be displayed and updated every second

Comment: Yep, just need small change in your `refreshLiveTime` function: `setLiveTime(new Date())` to `setLiveTime(moment(time).format("hh:mm:ss"))` and `const [liveTime, setLiveTime] = useState("00:00:00")`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with `moment` npm package.

```
moment(liveTime, "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm:ss A")
```

Where `liveTime` is `new Date()`